# Chrome - LocalStorage - Storing Values Across All URLs

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

I am developing a Chrome Extension where the user needs to be authenticated with our server every time they use the extension. I am trying to implement the 'Remember Me' feature where once the user has entered in the credentials, the extension will remember it forever. The problem I have come across is that Chrome will associate the credentials with the current website the user is on.

Right now, if the user enters in their credentials on google.com, the system will only remember their credentials on google.com, and not wikipedia.org. What I want to happen is that their credentials will be remembered across all domains.

To read the credentials:

```
username = localStorage["username"];
password = localStorage["password"];
```

To store the credentials:

```
localStorage["username"] = username;
localStorage["password"] = password;
```

To check if their credentials exist:

```
if ( localStorage["username"] != "" ) {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Chrome extension, the content scripts run in the same process and same domain (e.g. https://www.google.com) as the webpage. Meanwhile, any extension popups and background page run in the "extension" process and share a unique origin (e.g. "eakjnniffhfegdpfehmnpcmjiameincp"). Therefore, when you access `localStorage["username"]` from a content script, you're actually accessing the localStorage that belongs to e.g. https://www.google.com.

So if you want information to be shared between different content scripts in your extension, you need to store your data in `localStorage` on a background page and send messages from your content scripts to it by calling [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest) or [`chrome.extension.connect`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-connect). Or, send a message from the background page to the content scripts by calling [`chrome.tabs.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendRequest) or [`chrome.tabs.connect`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-connect).

As an aside, you may need to rethink your data model that seems to assume that the user has the same password on google.com and wikipedia.

Comment: Also, is there a way to ensure that the data stored in localStorage is not removed even after the tab closes, browser exits, or computer shuts down?

Comment: localStorage does not get cleared unless someone uninstalls the extension.